# How to enable show and hide search bar box

Tags: magento-1.9

How to show and hide the search bar input field I want to open it while I click on search bar icon?

Comment: you need to used custom code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

hope below code to help to you

```
    <div class="search-desktop">
    <ul class="search-fa-custom">
      <li><a id="searchtoggl"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
      <div id="searchbar" class="clearfix toggleClass" style="display: none;">  
Your Search Form
</div>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#searchtoggl").click(function(){
          jQuery("#searchbar").slideToggle();
        });
        });
```

Comment: how i call search bar iside it can can u gime me code

Comment: you have to just put the Form inside the div.